# d3 collapsible tree: how to color only the label of clicked node?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am developing collapsible tree graph (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).
I would change the color of label related to clicked node.
I modified the code

```
    // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
  }
```

width

```
    // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  d3.select(this).select("text")
   .style("fill", "red")
  update(d);
  }
```

but I don't know how to remember the previous clicked node to restore its label to black color.

Now if I click on a node the label text becomes red and so any other clicked. I would that to have in red only the last one. May anybody help me to do it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be colouring all texts, and then colouring the text of the clicked node:

```
d3.selectAll("text")
     .style("fill", "black");

d3.select(this).select("text")
    .style("fill", "red");
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/f6xmzjbr/